# wait for backend c++ in qml

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I have a `qml` frontend and c++ backend.
User enters numbers in frontend and the program send it to the backend.
Then it resend the answer to `qml` and qml show it.

But I have a problem:
When I run the program the `qml` doesn't wait for backend value and when a person enter number, it shows undefined number, before backend read numbers.

How can I impel the `qml` item to wait until backend sends response (just qml items who showing the answer)

**Update:**

I have a connection block like this :

```
Connections {
    target: receiver
    onSendToQml: {
        properyExample = "c"

    }

}
```

When i change a propery in block ( on send to qml ) program crashed .
How can fix it ? i receive my backend variable in it but i can't enter it
to a property .

Comment: Signals/Slots maybe

Comment: UI should be prepared for this scenario. For example you should show a loading icon or a spinner in `QML` until result is available.

Comment: You can create properties in the c++ backend and use it from qml frontend. There is a good documentation about this: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html

Comment: i integrated the file . i have a function in backend but qml has all thread but  i want out a part of qml from thread . can you write a example a qml file receive a number then send to c++ and then qml show the answer ? my problem is qml not wait to run backend and show answer before running the backend function . tnx

Comment: see the update , it's my main problem

Comment: As @MarekR suggested, you could have a `loading` or `pause` state while your backend is running. Once your C++ code finishes, emit a signal and change the qml item state to `showAnswer`. You can use the `state` property of items and the `onStateChanged` handler.